# How to get list of user having access to TIBCO Spotfire report?

Tags: reporting, spotfire, tibco, spotfire-analyst, spotfire-webplayer

Kindly suggest a rough idea to implement this :

We have close to 40 TIBCO Spotfire reports and all reports have dedicated ACTIVE DIRECTORY(AD GROUP) to restrict the users to access it .

**Now we want to create a dashboard for  listing  all the reports , but want to display only reports the logged-in user has access to (Out of 40+ reports he may be in only 5 AD group and reports with these 5 AD groups has to be displayed).**

Is there any mechanism of hand shaking with AD groups to get the user list ?

Or is there any other way of achieving this ?

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to mind is using ironpython to generate a list based on a search expression using the libraryManager class. [How to use library manager to organize the library](https://community.tibco.com/s/article/how-access-and-organize-spotfire-library-tibco-spotfirer-using-ironpython-scripting)

Since it will be parsed from the user context. You will only see the dashboards the user is allowed to see.
Admin can see all

Then again, writing 'type:dxp' in library search box shows the same.